# C++ mutual class dependency

Tags: c++, class, include, structure

I am writing a card game in C++. I have a *player* class, which handles the actions (i.e. selecting a card to lay). If the player is a human, it will use a *GUI class*, if it is a computer, it will use an *AI class*.

In order for the AI class to make decisions, it needs to know some things about every player that change during the game, for example the number of cards on hand. Right now I store a player pointer for every player in a vector in the AI class.

However, this leads to my problem, the AI class needs to #include the Player class, and the player class needs to #include the AI class.

Maybe the solution isn't how to handle the #includes, but rather a better way to structure the classes?

Comment: Note that you can usually use forward declarations e.g. `class player;` rather than including the whole definition, to avoid circular header dependencies. But it sounds like you'd be better off with a separate "visible state of the game" object anyway.

Comment: I think you may be thinking of it wrong. You have a "Payer" interface, which has things like "Number of Cards" and "Play Card". A player can be a "HumanPlayer" or an "AIPlayer".

Comment: You've not made the must-have case for your latter assertion; that the Player class need-know about the AI class. Ex: The UI activity of the Player should be attributed and nullified when the Player is AI, but AI makes that call and resulting provision; not Player. Either by derivation or a Traits design, either would work.

Comment: @MikeSeymour That visible state is actually a pretty good idea, I will try it, it also sounds simple to me, which is good :)

Answer (score 1):

I guess both Player and AI class have common methods for that card game (get card, put card, shuffle, bet, all in...) which can be inherited from a base class *CardPlayer* or composed during runtime using interfaces (see [Strategy Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern)).

To interface the Human Player class to the GUI, create a suitable interface, for example:

```
typedef struct PlayerInfoStruct {
    ---player info variables here---
};

class IGUIPlayer {
    virtual PlayerInfoStruct GetPlayerInfo(...) = 0;
    ---other methods exclusive to the GUI-player interaction here---
};
```

and implement that interface in your HumanPlayer inheriting it:

```
class HumanPlayer : public CardPlayer, public IGUIPlayer {
    PlayerInfoStruct GetPlayerInfo() {---method---}
    ---other methods here---
}
```

and in your GUI you point to each human player using its interface:

```
---somewhere in your GUI Class---
IGUIPlayer* humanplayer1 = <pointer to HumanPlayer>;
```

With that, GUI Class depends on IGUIPlayer. HumanPlayer depends on both IGUIPlayer and CardPlayer. AIPlayer depends only on CardPlayer. No circular stuff!

Using an interface means that you could, at any moment, provide AI players' info in the GUI, by simply inheriting *IGUIPlayer* to AIPlayer and implementing the pure virtual methods, without modifying the GUI a single bit. It took me a bit to get used to this (and I still keep on learning), but I can't resist to its inmense power.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it is not necessary to include header for a class in order to use it. For example, if you only use pointer or reference to a class, you can forward-declare it: instead of

```
#include "player.h"
class AI
{
  std::vector<player *> pl;
};
```

you can write

```
class player;
class AI
{
  std::vector<player *> pl;
};
```

Comment: This is actually what I tried first, but Xcode says _Member access into incomplete type 'Player'_

Comment: Have you written all functions that use that vector inside a cpp file and have you included `"player.h"` in it? If it still doesnt work, you can replace vector to a pointer to a vector or maybe `unique_ptr<vector<player *>>.