# C++: is it possible to late-initialize a class member function?

Tags: c++, class

I have the following code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class First {
    public:
        Second* x;
        void make_value(Second* sec_);
        First() {
            // Initialization
        }
};

class Second {
    public:
        First* y;
        Second() {
            // Initialization
        }
};

void First::make_value(Second* sec_) {
    x = sec_;
}

void main() {
    fir = new First();
    sec = new Second();
    fir->make_value(sec);
}
```

The two classes each have a member variable of the other class, which does not work for obvious reasons.

My question is whether or not there is a way to late-initialize variable `x` after class `Second` has been initialized. If not, what alternatives are there?

Comment: Some new class that would initialize *both* in its own ctor

Comment: Πώς θα μπορούσε να γίνει αυτό;

Comment: What is this code intended to accomplish?

Comment: You can always call some function later that initializes (rather; *assigns to*) stuff, but that's just bad style.

Comment: How could that work out?

Comment: Could you provide any links or articles that would help out?

Comment: You could have one class provide a constructor taking pointer as argument, and the other would pass `this`. But then be very careful about the possibility of using an object before its members are initialized.

Comment: I am afraid that this solution might not be suitable for the approach I am taking... I'll make some necessary edits.

Comment: @SidS doing that would not help, because class Second would still be referencing class First, which has not been initialized yet.

Comment: you know forward declarations ? (the typical solution for mutual dependency)

Comment: Nope. Haven't heard of that before... But it seems very useful. Thank you!

Comment: there must be a good dupe, but for now this is the best I could find: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21535351/4117728

Comment: Slightly better one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16802485/forward-declaration-circular-dependency

Comment: I have solved the issue thanks to your help. Would you like to post the answer so that I am able to close this?

Comment: Sidenote since it looks like you're new to C++, [Why should C++ programmers minimize use of 'new'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500313/why-should-c-programmers-minimize-use-of-new)

Comment: however, forward declaration dont help with everything. Depends on how much you left out from the example. See answer, only references or pointers can be used

Comment: Oh, thank you! I am indeed new to C++, and I am coming from a Python background, so this is good help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For any uses where the compiler doesn't need the definition of a class, a forward declaration will suffice. Pointers and references to types do not require a definition.

```
class Second; // forward declare

class First {
    public:
        Second* x;
        void make_value(Second* sec_);
        First() {
            // Initialization
        }
};

class Second {
    public:
        First* y;
        Second() {
            // Initialization
        }
};

void First::make_value(Second* sec_) {
    x = sec_;
}
```